# Why is Django saying my template doesn't exist even though it does?

Tags: django, templates, cmd, view

I'm a beginner following this Django tutorial (https://www.w3schools.com/django/django_templates.php) and I'm getting the error bellow after making the html template and modifying the views.py file (name erased for privacy):

```
Internal Server Error: /members
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\\myproject\myworld\members\views.py", line 5, in index
    template = loader.get_template('myfirst.html')
  File "C:\Users\\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 19, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: myfirst.html
[26/Oct/2022 16:51:01] "GET /members HTTP/1.1" 500 64964
```

Tried this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import loader

def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('myfirst.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render())
```

Expecting this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body><h1>Hello World!</h1>
<p>Welcome to my first Django project!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your html file located?

Comment: can you update the question with the directory structure and your settings.py file?

Comment: @Swift In C:\Users\\myproject\myworld\members

Answer (score 0):

first, you have to create a templates folder, then create into it your HTML file "myfirst.html", then create your HTML tags in it, for example:

```html
<h1>Hello, World</h1>
```

Comment: I did it. I literally copypasted everything.

Answer (score 0):

Create a directory where your `.html` will live:

1. create a `templates` directory in the `app` directory (i.e: `app/templates/app/template_name.html`)
2. Or, create a `templates` folder in the `project` directory (i.e: `templates/template_name.html` or `templates/app/template_name.html`), if you choose to go with this option, you'll have to point `django` to this directory by updating you `TEMPLATES` setting

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        # Add path to templates
        "DIRS": [BASE_DIR / "templates"],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

3. Then , in your views, specify the path to your `.html` file(s)

Example:

1. With option 1: the path will be `app/template_name.html`
2. With Option 2: the path will be `template_name.html` or `app/template_name.html` (depends on your folder structure)

Answer (score 0):

In order to better identify why your template is not rendered, you should take profit of `DEBUG=True` in `settings.py`
Trying to get access to your page via the browser should display the paths Django tried and then you will immediately see that your path is not correctly identified.

Comment: It is set to true.